# summing items in nested dictionary with different keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary along the lines of:

```
{'apple':  {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2},
 'orange': {'a': 4, 'c': 5},
 'pear':   {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

What I want to do is get rid of the outer keys and sum the values of the inner keys so that I have a new dictionary which looks like:

```
{'a': 6, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> d = {'apple': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2}, 'orange': {'a': 4, 'c': 5}, 'pear': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
>>> sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter())
Counter({'c': 7, 'a': 6, 'b': 6})
```

Comment: Great! Just what I needed. Thanks for the speedy response everyone

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for dct in yourdict.values():
    for k,v in dct.items():
        d[k] += v
```

The main advantage of this answer is that it works back to python2.5.  For python2.7+, see the solutions posted by @DSM and @BigYellowCactus.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) solution, it isn't a one-liner like the others but I think it is cleaner:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'apple': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2}, 'orange': {'a': 4, 'c': 5}, 'pear': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}

counts = Counter()
for v in d.values():
    counts.update(v)
```

Comment: Hmm ... who knew that `update` added the values in rather than replacing them ?  (Apparently you did +1).

Comment: I like this.  Sometimes `for` loops are the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 2):

The [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) object is designed to make things like this very easy:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {'apple': {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2}, 'orange': {'a': 4, 'c': 5}, 'pear': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
>>> sum((Counter(v) for v in d.itervalues()), Counter())
Counter({'c': 7, 'a': 6, 'b': 6})
```

Comment: I suppose if I just made the switch to python2.7, I could get in on this neat `Counter` action as well.  Nicely done (+1)

Comment: You should definitely make the switch to 2.7, if for no other reason than to answer SO questions. :^)

Comment: I don't actually use these data structures very often -- So most of what I've learned in `itertools` and `collections` (and probably a bunch of other modules in the stdlib) has been the result of answering SO questions ...