# Squash and sum values from 3-level nested dictionaries in one-liner (or two-liners)

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I was answering another OP's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216950/summing-nested-dictionary-entries) about how to add different items in nested dictionaries and I came up with a three nested `for` loops method to add items in a three level dictionary, which works, but meeeh... I'm pretty sure it can be done more concisely.

To provide a real use-case scenario: Let's say I have some data from a camera over some shop's entrance that counts how many people walk *in* and *out* of the store in 10 minutes intervals:

```
data = {
        "2014/01/01": {
            "15:00:00" : {
                "ins": 7,
                "outs": 5,
            },
            "15:10:00" : {
                "ins": 24,
                "outs": 10,
            },
            "15:20:00" : {
                "ins": 10,
                "outs": 20,
            },
        },
        "2014/01/02": {
            "15:00:00" : {
                "ins": 10,
                "outs": 10,
            },
            "15:10:00" : {
                "ins": 12,
                "outs": 5,
            },
            "15:20:00" : {
                "ins": 5,
                "outs": 10,
            },
        },
}
```

I'd like to *squash* those dictionaries together and add the *ins* and *outs* grouping them by a particular time, regardless of the date. Let's say I want to know "*how many people got in and out of my venue for each time bucket regardless of the date*" or with a different wording *"I want to know how many ins and outs total has there been since the beginning of time for each time bucket"*

That would be the result of adding the *ins* and *outs* for all the dicts whose key is the *time* found in the `data` dict (disregarding the first date "level") With the sample `data` provided above, that would be:

```
"15:00:00": {
    "ins": 17  # (7 + 10)
    "outs": 15 # (5 + 10)
},
"15:10:00": {
    "ins": 36  # (24 + 12)
    "outs": 15 # (10 + 5)
},
"15:20:00": {
    "ins": 15  # (10 + 5)
    "outs": 30 # (20 + 10)
}
```

Is there a way... somehow (I'm guessing through [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools), but I don't know which tools would be the right ones) of, starting with `data`, end up getting the result shown above in one line (or two)?

I've been fiddling with the answers found in

- [Sum the nested dictionary values in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645088/sum-the-nested-dictionary-values-in-python)
- [summing items in nested dictionary with different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080957/summing-items-in-nested-dictionary-with-different-keys)

But I can't figure out how to get what I want. I either get a list of `Counter` objects (and then I don't know what to do with them) or I get an error because I'm trying to add two `dict`s...

I know is really not big deal (three `for` loops get the job done), but I'm curious about the feasibility of this, and how to shorten my code (and probably learn about `itertools`, which is about time...)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you could do it with a combination of `sorted` and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) but I don't have time to leave a detailed answer right now.

Comment: Your code should be translatable into a nice one liner list comp but it would be kinda long and messy and probably not functionally different. Post your code maybe?

Comment: @user2782067, the best thing I could come up with (well... I was abusing `keys()` when I could use `values()`, but that I don't really care that much about) is in the answer that prompted this question (this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27217180/289011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done as a one liner. I've broken this into two lines, and even with that it's unreadable.

```
flattened = sorted((time,key,count) for day in data.values() for time,counters in day.items() for key,count in counters.items())
{time:{key:sum(datum[2] for datum in counters) for key,counters in itertools.groupby(group, lambda x:x[1])} for time,group in itertools.groupby(flattened, lambda x:x[0])}

{'15:20:00': {'outs': 30, 'ins': 15}, '15:00:00': {'outs': 15, 'ins': 17}, '15:10:00': {'outs': 15, 'ins': 36}}
```

Just because something *can* be done doesn't mean it *should* be done. I'd go with the clearest solution, and this isn't it.

Comment: yawwwzaa... Yeah, I agree... It looks uglier than I thought it would **:-D**

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit longer than two lines, but:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

flattened = (time for day in data.itervalues() for time in day.iteritems())
sums = defaultdict(lambda: Counter())

for time, entries in flattened:
    sums[time] += Counter(entries)
```

which gives:

```
In [116]: dict(sums)
Out[116]: 
{'15:00:00': Counter({'ins': 17, 'outs': 15}),
 '15:10:00': Counter({'ins': 36, 'outs': 15}),
 '15:20:00': Counter({'outs': 30, 'ins': 15})}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas DataFrames:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162021/764322

It would be 2 lines,one to create the dataframe (folowings previous questions answer) and another one to do a simple numpy sum() with the conditions you want, which could also be added at the end of the line and make it a one-liner (quite long though).

UPDATE: the code is not that ofuscated...

```
# Create data frame
>>> table = pd.DataFrame([[c2, d2['ins'], d2['outs']] for d1 in data.values() for c2, d2 in d1.items()])
>>> table
          0   1   2
0  15:20:00   5  10
1  15:00:00  10  10
2  15:10:00  12   5
3  15:20:00  10  20
4  15:00:00   7   5
5  15:10:00  24  10

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

Where column 1 are `ins` and 2 are `outs`.

```
>>> table.groupby(0).sum()
           1   2
0               
15:00:00  17  15
15:10:00  36  15
15:20:00  15  30
```

Comment: I'll look at it. I was hoping for something using built-ins, though. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Edited with the solution using pandas, in case you still are interested.

Comment: This is certainly valid, and interesting (probably *the right* way to accomplish what I'm asking) but it seems to deviate a bit from the original spirit of the question. It definitely deserves an *upvote* (that for sure).